# gensim исходники. Не могу найти модуль

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Разбираюсь в [gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim). Заклонил его и хотел запустить то, что есть в `gensim/gensim/example/dmlcz/gensim_xml.py`, например. Но там есть модули, которые я нигде не могу найти `gensim_build`, dmlcorpus `from gensim.corpora import dmlcorpus, MmCorpus`. Может кто подскажет?

Вот [здесь](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/tree/develop/gensim/examples/dmlcz) лежат эти примеры

Comment: Если устанавливать через `pip` нужные модули не подтягиваются?

Comment: @Streletz как я доберусь до `example`? Я хочу подебажить этот скрипт и посмотреть, что внутри происходит. Да, все модули собираются. Но мне нужно в потрохах разобраться.

Comment: Если ставите через `pip`, то у него наверняка, как у любого пакетного менеджера, есть специальная папка, где хранятся скачанные модули.

Comment: @Streletz разумеется. Но кажется, что здесь просто не хватает каких-то файлов для сборки внутри проекта. Их просто выпилили. Наверное, нужно по истории коммитов поглядеть

Comment: Разобрались. Нужно смотреть ветку develop